# Pycharm IDE not starting up although pycharm.exe is starting in task manager

Tags: pycharm

My machine restarted abruptly and now whenever I start pycharm IDE does not show up but pycharm.exe is visible in task manager

Answer (score 0):

1. Kill any pycharm.exe currently running in task manager.
2. Remove the files in folder
   C:\Users\user_name\Pycharm_folder\system\tmp
3. Start Pycharm